# cannot sign in on my Android device - Google 2-factor authentication

Tags: google, google-authenticator

So I'm trying to add my google acct to my device and it seems to be working fine up to the point where's it's asking me for the code sent to my phone via SMS.

I correctly put it in but the page goes to my "My Account" page which is not normal. On other devices, the page would normally close automatically and it continues on with adding my acct.

I've tried:

1. updating Play Store services to 8.1.x. I made use the -xxx matches when I downloaded the APK.
2. I tried verifying using backup code.
3. I tried verifying using Google Authenticator app.

Any ideas on how to fix this? thanks! :)

Comment: Are you trying to sign in to google in a browser?

Comment: no. I was trying to add my gmail account to my Android device. Settings => Add Account.

Comment: As a workaround you can disable the 2step authentication and add the email to your device and then turn on the 2 step verification.